# How do I interface with websockets as a client using Immutant?

Tags: clojure, websocket, immutant

I'm building a Clojure app that needs to interface with Slack's real time API, and that requires a connection to a Websocket.

I am aware this is possible with [gniazdo](https://github.com/stylefruits/gniazdo), but this pulls in Jetty, and I believe that Immutant has its own Websocket abstraction.

I've also tried using `clj-http`, but it does not recognise the `wss://` protocol, which is the URL returned from the Slack API.

Would greatly appreciate it if I were pointed in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immutant uses Undertow as it's web server, which provides the `wss` protocol support you seek. Sadly, looking through the Immutant clojure wrapper code I don't see any part touching this functionality, so you will have to use Clojure's Java interop facilities.

The relevant source seems to be implemented [here](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/websockets/client/WebSocketClient.java).

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably look at other web servers like Aleph.

Comment: This is correct - Immutant only implements websockets on the server side, and provides no client.